# Retrieve and compare filenames with folder name

Tags: perl

I try to code an algorithm searching for files having their filename matching to folder name they located in.

For example: the file structure is

```
    ./xyz/
        abdc.txt
        abcd.xls
        xyz.txt
        xyz.pdf
        lion.txt
        lion.pdf
```

I want to print files with names matching folder they located in.

For sample above the output should look like

```
./xyz/xyz.txt
./xyz/xyz.pdf
```

Bellow is my attempt to produce a code with this functionality

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
my $path = "C:\\";
opendir(DIR, $path);
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
my $name;
my $dir;
my $ext;
foreach my $sub(@files) {
    if($sub ne "." && $sub ne ".." && -d $path."\\".$sub && $sub ne "done") {
        print $sub."\n";
        opendir(DIR, $path."\\".$sub);
        my @fin = readdir(DIR);
        closedir(DIR);
        foreach(@fin) {

            if($_ ne "." && $_ ne ".." && $_ eq "error.txt") {
                last;
            } else {
                if($_ ne "." && $_ ne "..") {   
                        ($name,$dir,$ext) = fileparse($path."\\".$_,qr/\.[^.]*/);
                        #print $name."\n";
                        if ($name =~ m/^$sub.\.txt$/ and $name =~ m/^$sub.\.pdf$/) {
                            print $_."\n";
                        }
                                                    
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code does not produce desired output, could you point me in right direction to correct solution.

Addendum: possible solution is posted bellow

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = shift || die 'Provide directory name';

lookup($dir);

sub lookup {
        my $dir = shift;

        my($lookup) = $dir =~ /([^\/]*)$/;

        for my $item ( glob("$dir/*") ) {
                say $item       if $item =~ /\b$lookup\.[^\.]*$/;
                lookup($item)   if -d $item;
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you having? There are plenty of existing questions on StackOverflow (and on Google in general) about getting files from a directory; have you looked at them? StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service, and as such, "Requesting to provide a solution" is not a welcomed question.

Comment: I have pasted my code. Could you please look into my code and tell me what changes should i make

Comment: Much better, thanks. Now, please explain how the code is not working: do you have errors when running it (if so, tell us what the errors are)? Are the results not what you expect (if so, tell us what results you are getting compared to what you expect)?

Comment: I want to check if the filename(xyz.pdf) is same as filename(xyz.txt), if it is same, I want to compare it with foldername(xyz) and print the statement(filenames are similar).

Comment: if ($name =~ m/^$sub.\.txt$/ and $name =~ m/^$sub.\.pdf$/) {
     print $_."\n";
 }. I have used this condition but its not printing anything

Comment: Yes, and you have written a program to do so. Why do you need our help then? Presumably because your program is not working. Thus, I am asking you to edit your question in order to explain how your code is not working as expected.

Comment: I have edited my question. My code is not comparing the files and its not printing anything.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a module such as [`File::Find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Linux or WSL on Windows I would just do something like this:

```
perl -nle'@p=split"/";print if $p[-1]=~s/\.\w+$//r eq $p[-2]' files.lst
```

Test like this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/xyz
touch /tmp/xyz/{abdc.txt,abcd.xls,xyz.txt,xyz.pdf,lion.txt,lion.pdf}
find /tmp/xyz -type f
find /tmp/xyz -type f|perl -nlE'@p=split"/";say if $p[-1]=~s/\.\w+$//r eq $p[-2]'
```

The solution assumes no dirnames or filenames with `/` in themselves.